# Dealing with u"strings" in gdb

Tags: unicode, gdb

Why can't I cast `u"string"` to `wchar_t*` in gdb?

```
(gdb) print (wchar_t*)L"abc"
$60 = 0x568ae3b0 L"abc"
(gdb) print (wchar_t*)u"abc"
$61 = 0x567c5078 L"\x620061c\020I\x56640948\x567c50d0\x567c4f80\x567c4f30"
```

`u"string"` is an array of unsigned short which is almost the same as array of wchars.

Comment: `wchar_t` is NOT almost the same as `unsigned short` on linux, it's almost the same as `unsinged`.  On linux, `wchar_t` is for UTF-32, _not_ UTF-16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wchar_t` is NOT almost the same as `unsigned short` on linux, it's almost the same as `unsinged`. On linux, `wchar_t` is for UTF-32, not UTF-16.  You'll have to use a Unicode library to convert (probably ICU) .

You can cast it to `char32_t*` though.